# Apparmor: is it possible to call another executable from within an executable?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, server, apparmor

I have a problem I am not sure how to solve in AppArmor.

Basically I have a profile that executes a program, let us say

```
profile myprof {
    /my/executable ix,
}
```

The problem is that from that executable, I call another, spawning a process, let us call it, /the/other/executable.

How can I make AppArmor give /my/executable permissions to call /the/other/executable? This will be done when /my/executable is already running, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
profile myprof {
    /my/executable ix,
}
```

When you do write a rule like this, what you do is to allow `myprof` to execute `/my/executable` with *exactly* the same permissions that `myprof` has.
So if you want to allow `/my/executable` to do something you just need to add that permission to `myprof` and it will be **i**nherited by `/my/executable`.
But if you want to give that particular permission **exclusively** to `/my/executable` and to also to `myprof` you will need to use something else:

- ux      - unconfined execute
- Ux      - unconfined execute -- scrub the environment
- px      - discrete profile execute
- Px      - discrete profile execute -- scrub the environment
- cx      - transition to subprofile on execute
- Cx      - transition to subprofile on execute -- scrub the
  environment
- pix     - discrete profile execute with inherit fallback
- Pix     - discrete profile execute with inherit fallback -- scrub the
  environment
- cix     - transition to subprofile on execute with inherit fallback
- Cix     - transition to subprofile on execute with inherit fallback
  -- scrub the environment
- pux     - discrete profile execute with fallback to unconfined
- PUx     - discrete profile execute with fallback to unconfined --
  scrub the environment
- cux     - transition to subprofile on execute with fallback to
  unconfined
- CUx     - transition to subprofile on execute with fallback to
  unconfined -- scrub the environment

The difference between a discrete profile and a subprofile is that a discrete profile is a *normal* profile, a subprofile is define *inside* the current profile.